# Using regular expressions to split on = , == , and === separately

Tags: javascript, regex

i am having trouble with my code trying to split a string input up and save it to different lists by splitting on = , ==, and === so that each list only splits on the corresponding one

```
var tokenEquals = code.split(/[=]/gi);
var tokenDoubleEquals = code.split(/[==]/gi);
var tokenTrippleEquals = code.split(/[===]/gi);
```

so if if the code was "= == ===" each list should only have a length of 2

but what is happening is that it is splitting on every = and all of them end up with the same amount of 7

I have refined it down to

```
var tokenEquals = code.split(/\=(?!\=)/);
var tokenDoubleEquals = code.split(/\=\=(?!\=)/gi);
var tokenTrippleEquals = code.split(/\=\=\=/gi);
```

the current output is: Equals length is 4, Double Equals length is 3, and Tripple Equals length is 2

when they should all equal 1

so the triple one is working fine but the other 2 are not.
I am wondering what is the solution to put in the regexp fields to split on that will only cause them to only split on the correspond amount of equals.

bellow is an example of the code in action that currently returns [3, 2, 1] when I want it to return [1, 1, 1]

```js
var LLOCCounter = function() {};

LLOCCounter.prototype.count = function(code) {
  var numberOfLLOC = [];

  code = code.trim();


  var tokenEquals = code.split(/\=(?!\=)/);
  var tokenDoubleEquals = code.split(/\=\=(?!\=)/gi);
  var tokenTrippleEquals = code.split(/\=\=\=/gi);


  numberOfLLOC = [
    tokenEquals.length - 1, // 4 =
    tokenDoubleEquals.length - 1, // 5 ==
    tokenTrippleEquals.length - 1, // 6 ===
  ]

  console.log(numberOfLLOC)
};

contents = "= == ==="
llocCounter = new LLOCCounter();
numberOfLLOC = llocCounter.count(contents);
```

Comment: Do you need to just *count* the resulting split chunks of text? Or eventually get those chunks as well?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just need to count it no need to use it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the mimicking negative lookbehind technique described in the [*Mimicking Lookbehind in JavaScript*](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) article.

The idea is to pre-process the symbol(s) you need to split against with something you can easily use in the `split` method. I suggest using literals like `_SiNgLe_` or similar:

```
code = code.trim().replace(/(=)?=(?!=)/g, function($0, $1){  // Pre-process single =
    return $1 ? $0 : '_SiNGlE_';
});
code = code.replace(/(=)?==(?!=)/g, function($0, $1){  // Pre-process double =
    return $1 ? $0 : '_DoUbLe_';
});
code = code.replace(/(=)?===(?!=)/g, function($0, $1){    // Pre-process triple =
    return $1 ? $0 : '_TrIpLe_';
});

var tokenEquals = code.split("_SiNGlE_");              // Split with the temp tokens
var tokenDoubleEquals = code.split("_DoUbLe_");
var tokenTrippleEquals = code.split("_TrIpLe_");
```

So, basically, this is how it works: `(=)?=(?!=)` contains an optional capturing group in front (`(=)?`) that can capture a `=` or will be empty, then `=` is matched (in the other two patterns, `==` or `===` respectively), and then no `=` should follow (thanks to the negative lookahead `(?!=)`). Inside the `replace` method, a callback is used to analyze the match data structure: if Group 1 (that is optional) is matched, that means a `=` is present before the `=` (or `==`, or `===`) and we do not want to match that `=` (or `==` or `===`). The `$1 ? $0 : '_SiNGlE_'` piece of code does just that: `$0` stands for the whole match (if `$1` (i.e. Group 1 value) is not empty, just reinsert the text found, else, replace with a temporary token.

```js
var LLOCCounter = function() {};

LLOCCounter.prototype.count = function(code) {
  var numberOfLLOC = [];

  code = code.trim().replace(/(=)?=(?!=)/g, function($0, $1){  // Pre-process single =
   return $1 ? $0 : '_SiNGlE_';
  });
  code = code.replace(/(=)?==(?!=)/g, function($0, $1){  // Pre-process double =
   return $1 ? $0 : '_DoUbLe_';
  });
  code = code.replace(/(=)?===(?!=)/g, function($0, $1){    // Pre-process triple =
   return $1 ? $0 : '_TrIpLe_';
  });

  var tokenEquals = code.split("_SiNGlE_");              // Split with the temp tokens
  var tokenDoubleEquals = code.split("_DoUbLe_");
  var tokenTrippleEquals = code.split("_TrIpLe_");


  numberOfLLOC = [
    tokenEquals.length - 1, // 4 =
    tokenDoubleEquals.length - 1, // 5 ==
    tokenTrippleEquals.length - 1, // 6 ===
  ]

  console.log(numberOfLLOC)
};

contents = "= == ==="
llocCounter = new LLOCCounter();
numberOfLLOC = llocCounter.count(contents);
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was stuck on that for so long it works perfectly. Now I just need to go and learn how it works hahah
@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I  added some explanation.

Comment: sry my account was to new to upvote but now i have enough points i can and i just did so all good :)